# What is the equivalent to Laravel Eloquent's belongsTo in raw MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Probably a dumb question. But say I have 2 tables, `teams` and `images`. The `teams` table has a field `image_id`. In my Eloquent model for `Team`, I have:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
}
```

When I want to get a team's image, I invoke `$team->image`. What I want to do is to make this request in raw MySQL. So far I have this:

```
SELECT teams.*, images.*  
FROM `teams` 
    LEFT JOIN images ON teams.image_id = images.id 
WHERE teams.id = 1
```

Is this the correct approach? Could it be improved?

Comment: Got any problem with your query?

Comment: See this is why I disagree with @tadman that developers ought to start life using a framework

Comment: @RiggsFolly See your point, personally I think starting with a framework is fine, but it's no excuse not to learn the fundamentals of the technologies you're using.

Comment: This is precisely why I'm asking this question, trying to learn the fundamentals. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Hi, that comment was NOT aimed at you in any way my friend

Comment: Neither was mine btw, it was in response to Riggs :P

Comment: Ok, fair enough, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the following command:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();

//do query
$team = Team::all();
$image = $team->image;

dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

You will have an output like:

```
select * from teams

select * from images where team_id = ? (? => the team id number)
```

Laravel uses ActiveRecord pattern. You can google it.
So, Laravel doesn't use JOIN, but sequentials `select`.

The query you are looking for is exactly the one you have:

```
SELECT teams.*, images.*  
FROM `teams` 
LEFT JOIN images ON teams.image_id = images.id 
WHERE teams.id = 1
```

But, under the hood, that is not the way Laravel does.

Comment: Thanks! Is the JOIN approach more performant than the AR approach? Or vice versa?

Comment: JOIN is more performatic, but AR makes things easier to manipulate data through the application. This isn't a straight decision. You need to see the pros and cons in each approach and decide by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is This the proper SQL query?

**YES**

Can it be improved?

**YES**

Select only the image. For example:

```
SELECT images.url as image_url  
FROM `teams` 
    LEFT JOIN images ON teams.image_id = images.id 
WHERE teams.id = 1
```